# Str not callable

Tags: python-3.x, windows, multithreading

I am using threading to speed up my processes, but it says my thread is not callable.
Code:

```
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=next_word())
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=get_word())
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
```

The error is this:

> Exception in thread Thread-1:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
>       self.run()
>     File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\threading.py", line 862, in run
>       self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
>   TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

I do not know what is wrong with my code, if you can help at all that will be great. I know there is two errors, but they are the same so by fixing one, the other can be fixed.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are expected to give a function for `Thread` as target.

While `next_word` is a function, `next_word()` is not. Instead, it is the result of the function, that is probably a string.

So what is happening is your `Thread` will call `next_word()()`, i.e `"a string"()` which obviously doesn't make sense since a string can't be called, hence your `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`.

**Fix :**

```
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=next_word)
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=get_word)
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
```